# T-SQL QUERY setting the date between

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a report and I'm out of logic for this one. I joined four tables, but for simplicity let's say I have two tables, Table1 and Table 2.

- `Table1` has these columns: `WorkDateTime, ColTest1, ColTest2, UserName`
- `Table2` has these columns: `UserName, INdateTIme, OUTdateTime`

What I need to achieve: join these two tables by `Username` and the `WorkDateTime` must be between (or equal) to the `INdateTIme` and `OUTdateTime` and the `WorkDateTime` is based on the user's input.

Something like this example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.UserName = Table2.UserName
                  AND Table1.WorkDateTime BETWEEN Table2.INdateTIme AND Table2.OUTdateTime
WHERE Table1.WorkDateTime BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2018-02-01 00:00:00.000') AND CONVERT(date, '2018-02-07 00:00:00.000')
```

My tables have a thousand records. But please see below sample data. My query above returns `0` data.

[image]

My query should only return the first five data from `Table1` since in `Table2` Username `EmpNo1` only works between **5:40am** to **2:00pm** on **Feb 1st**. The last two data from `Table1` is beyond 2:00pm.

Comment: are you not getting the expected results? Sample data and expected output would help...

Comment: @scsimon it returns no data. I edit my question and add a few sample data.

Comment: Your query seems to be correct. The reason maybe in datetime conversion. Try to pass date in language independent format `YYYYMMDD` to `convert` function. Like `CONVERT(date, '20180201')`

Comment: @uzi I tried this one and it works. See my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I revised my query to this one (as per @uzi advised) and it works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.UserName = Table2.UserName
                  AND CONVERT(datetime, Table1.WorkDateTime) BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, Table2.INdateTIme) AND  CONVERT(datetime, Table2.OUTdateTime)
WHERE CONVERT(date,Table1.WorkDateTime) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2018-02-01 00:00:00.000') AND CONVERT(date, '2018-02-07 00:00:00.000')
```

I just add the `CONVERT()` function. I'm confused, my tables have the same format but it won't run. I guess, just to be safe, I should include the `CONVERT()` function everytime.

Comment: what's the datatype of the WorkDateTime column? I know it LOOKS like a date, but is it a varchar()?

Comment: @scsimon datatype is datetime, actually columns are in datetime type (WorkDateTime, INdateTIme and OUTdateTime).

Comment: Very odd indeed. I would not expect the need for conversion. I’m definitely going to try and replicate this tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A cross apply would allow you to filter

```
where table1.date > table2.indate and table1.date < table2.outdate.
```

This isn't going to perform well on a large dataset.

Comment: I tried this but it returns me no data. I edit my question and add a few sample data. Please look.